# How to map the simplevalue type of Set collection using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

Could anyone please explain me how to use Simple value type of Set, by using annotation mapping without using one to many relationship. I have shown example in this below code. In this code I have person name and person petnames, here the person petname is the simple value type of the Set. I want map to the person name in the one table in the one table and petnames in the other table.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Set<String> petname;

    public Set<String> getPetname() {
        return petname;
    }

    public void setPetname(Set<String> petname) {
        this.petname = petname;
    }





    public boolean addPetNames(String a) {

        return petname.add(a);

    }
```

Comment: Hi can u help me out for this quetion

Answer (score 0):

The JPA annotation works like this:  (quite self explaining I think)

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="PET_NAMES",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID")
)
@Column(name="PET_NAME")
private Set<String> petname;
```